# Auto-dismiss "welcome back" message if you upvote

Tags: feature-request, voting, notification-bar

When I go back to a site I haven't been to in a long while (e.g. ServerFault), there is a "welcome back" banner that displays at the top and reminds me to upvote the questions/answers if I find them useful.

I don't need the reminder, but that's okay—I have no objection to its existence.

However, I noticed today after I upvoted the question and answer I was reading, the banner was still there.

**Could we please have the "welcome back!" banner auto-dismiss if the user upvotes a question and/or answer?**